# What type of test to run on my data?

Tags: anova, t-test

I am having difficulty trying to figure out what test to run with my data.

An experiment was performed with and without a robotic system. While using the robotic system, the user performed while the end-effector was positioned at 90° and at 45°. Experiments were repeated several times and 3 measurements were recorded/calculated (let us call them A, B, C). This experiment was performed without the robotic system.

So I have 2 groups (with vs. no robot), 2 experiments (90° vs. 45°) and 3 recorded measurements. I want to compare a measurement with vs. without the robot (*i.e.* Robot.90.A vs. NoRobot.90.A), but I also want to compare the measurements within a single group (*i.e.* Robot.90.B vs. Robot.45.B).

I have been doing independent t-test but I think I am doing this wrong. I think running an ANOVA is a better option but I don't know what are my groups nor how to set it up.

I use PRISM as my tool if it's of any help.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are describing a [mixed-model ANOVA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixed-design_analysis_of_variance) test. The "mixed" part of mixed model means that you have both different experimental groups as well as different measurements.

I'm not familiar with PRISM, but generally the different measures are labelled as within-subjects effects. You have three levels (measurement A, measurement B, measurement C).

The other two factors are generally labelled between-subjects factors. You have two different ones (robot vs no-robot; 90 degrees vs 45 degrees). You had mentioned wanting to test specific groups such as "Robot.90.B" - this suggests to me that you want to test for an interaction effect between the two between-subject factors. If you have a significant interaction effect, then talking about the experimental group which had robot assistance and the 90-degree tool placement.

Otherwise, if there is no significant interaction your analysis comes down to robot vs no robot and 45-degree placement vs 90-degree.

Comment: I will take a look into a mixed-model ANOVA test. In the meantime, do you think it would be inappropriate to just stick with running t-tests and compare each measurement I am interested in? Or, would it be ill-advised to do so?

Comment: @gelman_grad ANOVA is basically a t-test that has been expanded to include multiple groups. So it's not totally unreasonable. ANOVA will be better though. Two things to think about: 1.) You'll have to run a lot of t-tests. That will dramatically increase your odds of type 1 error. ANOVA avoids this by bundling them all into one test. 2.) Since you have multiple measures you should consider a paired-sample t-test for comparing measures. Again, the repeated measures ANOVA will be better.

Comment: @gelman_grad If this answer was helpful to you, please consider upvoting it. If it solved your problem please accept it.

Comment: is a repeated measures ANOVA the same as a mixed-model ANOVA?

Comment: @gelman_grad A basic (one-way) ANOVA has a single measure of a single dimension on which subjects are grouped. A repeated measures ANOVA has multiple measures. A mixed-model ANOVA has both multiple measures and more than one dimension that subjects are being grouped on (for example, you have two dimensions: robot assistance or none, and the angle of the instrument).